# How to describe recurring incomplete time intervals?

Tags: json, calendar, iso8601

How would one describe (preferably in a standards-compliant way) some recurring, but imprecise time intervals in a JSON? For example, how to describe a product that can be purchased every day but only in the mornings, from 9am to 11am?

Something like

`"product": { "id": 42, "purchaseInterval": ??? }`

Comment: iCal RRULE format is the thing to use. It can formulate almost every odd-ball repeat rule. Daily from 9 to 11 would probably look something like `RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=9,10,11`. The applicable standard is RFC 2445. Look at some [hands-on examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse004.htm#ADMIN12415), the [spec](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-5-3-recurrence-rule.html) and a [handy help page](https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/) on the iCal format. Parser libraries are widely available, though not necessarily every one implements every feature.

Comment: Alternatively you would use an event that is three hours long and simply repeats every day, any iCalendar implementation can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Being possible values of frequencyUnit enum: years, months, weeks, days

I think you can have a very standard / easy to understand / complete description with the following JSON:

```
"product": {
    "id": 42,
        "purchaseInterval": {
            "startTime": "9:00",
            "endTime": "11:00",
            "frequencyUnit": "weeks",
            "frequencyValue": 1,
            "weekdays": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
    }
}
```

In addition, consider weekdays as another enum collection.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `24 hour` format and specify the range like

```
"product": { "id": 42, "purchaseInterval": "9:00-11:00" }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the "recurring" part of the question, nor is it standards compliant.